# Exponential families and Gibbs measures? Any relation?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, exponential-family

The title says it all. The formulas for exponential families and Gibbs measures seems very similar. Is there any relationship, or some kind of translation table?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are close parallels. Let us write an exponential family in the form
$$ \tag{expfam}\label{expfam}
  g(x)\cdot\exp\left( b(\theta)^T T(x) - A(\theta)  \right)
$$
while Gibbs measures are typically written 
$$ \tag{Gibbs}\label{Gibbs}
  \frac1{Z(\eta)}\exp\left( -\eta \cdot E(x)  \right)
$$
$g(x)$ is the base measure, and have no corresponding part in the Gibbs measure formula, but it could have been included. Often we write the exponential family with a canonical parameter by defining $\eta=b(\theta)$, we can see the Gibbs measure is written then in canonical parameter form.  To see the parallels, first write \eqref{expfam} with the canonical parameter as
$$\tag{*}\label{*}
  g(x)\cdot\exp\left( \eta^T T(x) - A(b^{-1}(\eta))  \right)
$$  and \eqref{Gibbs} more resembling the exponential family form
$$ \tag{**}\label{**}
  \exp\left( \eta \cdot ( -E(x))-\log Z(\eta)  \right)
$$ which makes some differences more clear. In \eqref{*} $\eta$ might be a vector, likewise the *canonical statistic* $T$ might be a vector, while in \eqref{**} $\eta$ is typically a scalar while the *energy function* (or *potential function*) $E$ is a scalar.  So we see that a Gibbs measure is just a one-parameter exponential family, usually with some changes in terminology.

The *partition function* $Z(\eta)$, note that in \eqref{*} we can write $A(b^{-1}(\eta))=\log Z(\eta)$, is related to the mgf (moment generating function) of the canonical statistic $T$.

Comment: I do not understand the distinction made in this answer: a Gibbs distribution is truly a special case of a one-dimension exponential family.